# Visualforce compile time error when using Vue.js v-on:click directive

Tags: visualforce

Visualforce documentation says this about using applyHtmlTag and applyBodyTag:

> When either is set to false, you are fully responsible for adding the
>   corresponding tags to your markup. In this mode, Visualforce won’t
>   prevent you from creating nonsense tag combinations or attributes that
>   give even modern browsers fits.

But it seems the compiler just can't help wanting to be opinionated about my html.
When using the v-on:click="doSomething" or @click="doSomething" directives in Vue.js it generates errors when saving.

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button @click="doIt">Just Do It</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.25/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        methods: {
          doIt: function(e) {
            console.log('done');
          }
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

The SF compiler gods say:

```
Element type "button" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

When using v-on:click="doSomething" they tell me:

```
Error Parsing /apex/VueControllerTest: Error Traced[line: 9] The prefix "v-on" for attribute "v-on:click" associated with an element type "button" is not bound.
```

Is there another  attribute I've missed that will allow my 'nonsense tag combinations or attributes' or am I misunderstanding what is meant in the docs?

Comment: The second error is saying that the namespace prefix "v-on" is not bound to a namespace. Perhaps adding a definition for that prefix e.g. `<html xmlns:v-on="http://fake.org/fake">` will fool Visualforce and leave Vue.js working...

Comment: Brilliant!  Yes, the v-on:click version compiles with that!  Thank you!  Do you want to repost that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second error is saying that the namespace prefix "v-on" is not bound to a namespace. (Visualforce must be [well-formed XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).)

Adding a definition for that prefix e.g.:

```
<html xmlns:v-on="http://fake.org/fake">
```

fools Visualforce and leaves Vue.js working. (See comments on question.)

If the problem was with the JavaScript (rather than the HTML) then moving that to a static resource avoids any processing being done - the static resource is just directly served to the client. In AngularJS, it is also possible to move the HTML into static resources and only have a single Visualforce page that loads initially and then pulls in the HTML. That type of approach may also be possible with Vue.js (check out Monith's links), though probably only worth pursuing if you are going to do significant development in Vue.js.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this will be to do all development locally using proper file structure and webpack as documented below

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews

And only use the final static file generated (build.js) into the static resource of the SFDC .

This will require some tooling set up to intitally begin with using Gulp.js or Grunt but once you set up this ,it should be easier to test and debug .

I wrote a post on how to do this for [React](http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2015/10/setting-up-dev-tools-for-salesforce.html) ,the principles would be same here as well .There is also [one](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/developing-react-redux-apps-in-salesforce-s-visualforce-3ad7be560d1c#.vustid3w4) from Raja on how to use ngrok and develop offline .

Comment: I don't understand how extracting out the JavaScript solves the issue.

Comment: @ScottMcClung That will definitely fix it because HTML will be served from static resource .Although I have not tried myself yet but would love to do this and prove this .